# How to find pdf of a generic sum of $n$ r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to find the PDF of the variable $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ where $X_i\in(0,1)$ i.i.d. with $p_X(x)=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$.

It's easy to find the characteristic function of $S_n$

$\phi_{S_n}(s)=[\lambda s^{-\lambda} (\Gamma[\lambda] - \Gamma[\lambda, s])]^n$

However it's very difficult/impossible to compute the inverse Laplace transform directly. However, since it's very easy to work out the moments and comulants, I was thinking to reconstruct the PDF using them. I have read about the Hamburger moment problem and so on but these do not explain how to reconstruct the PDF. Is there a way to reconstruct the PDF from the moments/comulants? Do you know other ways to find the PDF?

Any idea, reference support is well accepted!!

Comment: Not an easy task. $X_i$ are Beta distributed with parameters $(1,λ)$. There is not a closed a form for the sum of iid Betas. But if you want to apply CLT or something alike to obtain a normal approximation then you can

Comment: The point is that I would like to find the pdf for few $n$ so I cannot apply the CLT.. There is not a way to approximate the PDF using the moments?

Comment: I do not know any way myself and an internet search for "sum of iid beta's" does not provide much. I don't think that there is a way, but perhaps someone else does...

Comment: Cursory google search shows that the problem of reconstructing distribution from its moments has been (extensively) studied - including approximations based on finite number of moments. Do you need an exact solution or an approximation? What is the range of interest for $\lambda$? Do you need the pdf itself or some other property of the distribution? Sidenote: $X_i$ are distributed as a radius of a uniform sample from a unit $\lambda$-dimensional ball.

Comment: It's seems that an exact solution is not possible to find so a good approximation is ok right now ;) I am especially interested on the pdf  in the case $0<\lambda<1$

Comment: Since for $\lambda$ not far from $1$, even moderate $n$ will put you close to normal, you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution#Version_2 But the main question is why do you need the (approximate) pdf? What is the real problem behind it?

Comment: for the sum of uniform distribution, you get the Irwin-Hall distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution which you can at least have some recurrence relationship to calculate the pdf, with the aid of computer. I guess you may be able to derive similar result for this beta distribution, in case $n$ is not too large.

Comment: The real problem is something like this: I have $n$ molecules and $x_i$ represent the time at which molecule $i$ turns on ( in a scale (0,1) i.e $x_i=0$ means molecule $i$ never turns on and $x_i=1$ it turns on immediately). When a molecule turns on it starts to emit light with an intensity that grow exponentially.

Comment: Macroscopically we will start to see the light after a time $\Delta t$ ( since the total intensity has to reach a certain value ). I know the relation between the waiting time and $S_n$: $\Delta t=-log(\frac{S_n}{n})$. Clearly for $n\to\infty$ we have $t=-log(E(x))$. But if I have just a few molecules how can I know the $\Delta t$ distribution? I.e it's possible to find a relation between the number of particle and the macroscopical waiting time $\Delta t$?

Comment: Never seen such time-parametrization before - is the an alternative formulation for the usual $[0,\infty)$ parametrization? Why are you adding $X_i$ without weighting them by $e^{\lambda(x_i)}$? The way you presented, $\Delta t= 0$ for $n=1$ and $X_1=1$ - which contradicts the claim that we need to wait for intensity to ramp up.